# Python Subprocess returncode - different results

Tags: python, return-value, subprocess

I came to run a script on a production box, and it failed in one of it's first checks. I've narrowed it down to the fact my "ping" check (invoked by subprocess) is returning a non-zero result.

Here's the code in it's simplest form:

```
import subprocess
import sys
ip="127.0.0.1"
ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "2", "-w", "1", ip], shell=False)
ping.wait()
if ping.returncode != 0:
    print ping.returncode, "ERROR: failed to ping host. Please check."
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    print "OK"
```

Both servers are CentOS 5.5 & Python 2.4.3, but one works and one doesn't!

From the command line a manual ping (of 127.0.0.1) returns 0 in both cases. Why is their a difference when using the subprocess module in python?

Cheers.

Comment: can't you see what is the output of that failed ping?

Comment: Need more details. What are the outputs (stdout) of ping in all 4 cases (server1,server2 X python,shell)? Is the failing ping (inside Python) completely reproducible? Are the ping executables different in some way (try checksumming them)? Does it help if you increase the deadline time?